# How to only display fragments on navigation drawer if logged in

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am new to android development. I will like to understand how i can develop a navigation drawer and only display specific fragments if the user is logged in. I have googled with no luck.

Example If user not logged in, the fragments the should see are:

- Login
- Store
- Help

But if they are logged in, the fragments should be:

- Store
- Orders
- Account
- Settings

`Store` is common because i want users to still be able to browse the store without login.

Do i need to create multiple drawers? One on a MainActivity which do not require login and another with the logged in fragments on a second Activity ie CustomerActivity?

Please any advice/guide would be appreciated.

I do not expect any code but if you have any, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two menu resources files (**menu_logged_in.xml** and **menu.xml**) under the menu resources directory. **(res / menu / xml files here)**

**E.g menu.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item   android:id="@+id/menu_login"
                android:title="@string/string_menu_login"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_login"/>

        <item   android:id="@+id/menu_store"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_store"
                android:title="@string/string_menu_store"/>

        <item   android:id="@+id/menu_help"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_help"
                android:title="@string/string_menu_help"/>
</menu>
```

Then in your **onCreateOptionsMenu()** you can check wether is logged in or not and inflate your menu according to that.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater

        if(loggedIn)
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_logged_in, menu)
        else
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)

        return true
      }
```

Remember to manage all ids in your **onOptionsItemSelected()** method to give them some actions:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.menu_store -> {
                //go to fragment store
            }
            R.id.menu_settings -> {
                //go to settings
            }
            R.id.menu_login -> {
                //go to login
            }
            ...etc
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```